# Select a changing specific part in a sentence

Tags: r

I have a use case in which I have to split a sentence into parts.
The part that has be cut off has a date stamp (formatted like - 30.12.17/13.24)

A sample of a text looks like this:

```
  "BEA   NR:JH8D78   30.12.17/13.24 ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH,PAS599"
```

And the part that I would like to cut out is:

```
 "ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH"
```

So the part after `"30.12.17/13.24"` and before: `",PAS599"`

My idea it do it like this:

1. look for a pattern in the sentence which contains two numeric value, a dot and again two numeric values `(13.24)`
2. then look for the position in the sentence and cut it off.
3. apply a simple strsplit for getting  rid of PAS599.

Any feedback on whether this is the right way to go? My assumption is that there smarter ways to cut it....?

Comment: Are you planning to have many cases like this (where you have some date formatted similarly, and a comma-separated value at the end, and all you want is the stuff in the middle?)

Answer (score 0):

I would do two splits:
1.- split based on the slash "/", then two alphanumeric characters, a dot, two alphanumeric characters.
2.- then take the second part of the first split and split again using the comma.

For the example:

```
t <- "BEA NR:JH8D78 30.12.17/13.24 ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH,PAS599"
res <- paste(strsplit(t, "/\\d+.\\d+\\s", perl = T)[[1]][1], strsplit(t, ",", perl = T)[[1]][2], sep = ",")
res
[1] "BEA NR:JH8D78 30.12.17,PAS599"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will do it in a general way

Here's an example

```
# install.packages('stringr')
library(stringr)
sample = "BEA NR:JH8D78 30.12.17/13.24 ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH,PAS599"
pattern = regex(".*\\s\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d+/\\d+[.]\\d+\\s*(.*),.*", perl=T)
result = str_match(sample, pattern)
result[2]
```

In approximate English the regex is doing the following

Look for any character then some whitespace then the pattern of digits followed by some optional white space. At this point start a capturing group and remember anything until a comma.

The second element of the `str_match` result is the contents of the capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `stringr` package to do your work - there's a lot of ways to do regex but `stringr's` syntax is a bit more straightforward. Below is my suggestions based on making it into a function - this is assuming you perhaps have many cases that are structured the same but have different data.

```
library(stringr)

my_string = 'BEA NR:JH8D78 30.12.17/13.24 ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH,PAS599'r)

get_middle <- function(my_string){
  date <- "(([0-9]{2}[.]){2})[0-9]{2}[/]([0-9]{2}[.])[0-9]{2}[ ]"
  after_date <- str_split(my_string, date)[[1]][2] # Remove date and all before
  final <- strsplit(after_date, ',')[[1]][1] # Remove comma and all after
  return(final)
}
```

You could make this even more concise if you want, but in a nutshell this is just creating a pattern to match the date:

- `[0-9]` matches a single number of any digit;
- Braces (`{` and `}`) say how many times in a row to match the previous entry
- `[.]` and [`/`] match a period and slash literal, respectively

Then I separately split on the comma afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I like [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) when the incoming text doesn't have nice delimiters.  But it does require more effort than `strsplit()`.  If this task were the only thing youd do like this, then learning regexes probably isn't worth it.  But once you learn them, you'll see a lot of opportunity to leverage them.

The following regex pattern extracts/captures "13.24" and "ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH".  It's a little hidden in the pattern, but the parentheses are what make everything work.  They [capture](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) those elements of the input you want to capture/extract.  Then `gsub()` *substitutes* the whole match with either the first ("\1") or second ("\2") group.

```
pattern <- "^.+?/(\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}) (.+?),\\w{2,}\\d{3,}$"
ds <- tibble::tibble(
  x = c(
    "BEA NR:JH8D78 30.12.17/13.24 ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH,PAS599",
    "ABC NR:JH8D78 30.12.17/09.00 Piggly Wiggly 91 Dorestad,PAS601"
  )
)
```

This [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/ke6foD/1/) explains the different tokens used in the pattern above.  It it also a starting point if you need to make the pattern more flexible.  (I made some assumptions about the types of geospatial input you'd have to read from your client.)  When you move the pattern from the tester into R, remember to escape the backslashes (which essentially means turing single backslashes into doubles).

```
ds$y1 <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern, "\\1", ds$x))
ds$y2 <- gsub(pattern, "\\2", ds$x)


> ds[, c("y1", "y2")]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     y1                        y2
  <dbl>                     <chr>
1 13.24  ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH
2  9.00 Piggly Wiggly 91 Dorestad
```

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form assuming `",PAS"` is fixed character at end. I have used a `vector` to showcase converting multiple lines where each line will become an element of `vector`.

```
v <- c("BEA NR:JH8D78 30.12.17/13.24 ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH,PAS599")

lst <- lapply(strsplit(v, "\\/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+ |,PAS[0-9]+", perl = TRUE), function(x){
  x[2]
})

#> lst
#[[1]]
#[1] "ALBERT HEIJN 1311 UTRECH"
```